# Why does C# compiler does not complain with Overflow for this obvious 'bad' casting?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, clr, overflow

I cannot understand why the code below compiles.

```
public void Overflow()
{
    Int16 s = 32767;
    s = (Int16)  (s + 1);
}
```

At the compile time it is obvious that (s+1) is not a Int16 anymore as we know the value of s.

And CLR allows casting to :

- To its own type
- Or any of the base-types (because it is safe)

As Int32 is not Int16 and Int16 is not base type of Int32.

**Question**: So why the compiler does not fail for the casting above? Can you please explaint it from the CLR and compiler point of view?

Thanks

Comment: You use the cast to *suppress* the overflow.  If you want one then use Convert.ToInt16() instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type of the expression `s + 1` is `Int32` - both operands are converted to `Int32` before the addition is performed. So your code is equivalent to:

```
public void Overflow()
{
    Int16 s = 32767;
    s = (Int16)  ((Int32) s + (Int32) 1);
}
```

So the overflow only actually occurs in the explicit cast.

Or, to put it another way: because the language specification says so. You should describe one of:

- Why you think the compiler is violating the language specification
- The exact change you're proposing to the language specification

EDIT: Just to make things really clear (based on your comments), the compiler wouldn't allow this:

```
s = s + 1;
```

when `s` is an `Int16` *whatever* the value of `s` might be known to be. There's no `Int16 operator+ (Int16, Int16)` operator - as shown in section 7.8.4 of the C# 4 spec, the integer addition operators are:

```
int operator +(int x, int y);
uint operator +(uint x, uint y);
long operator +(long x, long y);
ulong operator +(ulong x, ulong y);
```

Comment: Yes. And also the language spec does not say that the compiler is supposed to do data flow analysis and "know" that s will have a constant value (except if you actually declared it as const, which you didn't).

Comment: Jus as a note - S+1 is int32 because "1" is int32.

Comment: @usr: If it does not do any analysis then why "s =  s + 1;" does not compile?

Comment: @TomTom: I think the reason is you go beyond the boundry of Int16

Comment: Because (s+1) is typed as Int32 and does not fit into a Int16, regardless of the runtime value it has. Just look at the compiler message. It says nothing about overflow. It complains about types.

Comment: @TomTom I was under the impression that C# inherits the C rule that *all* arithmetic operations on built-in types are carried out in `int` or larger.

Comment: @TomTom: No, it would be `Int32` even if you used S + T where both operands were `Int16`. There aren't addition operators for `byte` or `short`.

Comment: @pencilCake The compiler cannot assume these things if you do not mark `s` as `const`.

Comment: @pencilCake: `s = s + 1;` doesn't compile because the result of `s + 1` is an `Int32` and there's no implicit conversion from `Int32` to `Int16`.

Answer (score 1):

"At the compile time it is obvious that (s+1) is not a Int16 anymore as we know the value of s."

*We* know the value of s + 1 is too large for a short; the compiler does not. The compiler knows three things:

1. You have a short variable 's'
2. You assigned it a valid short constant.
3. You performed an integral operation between two values that have implicit conversions to int.

Yes, in *this specific case* it is trivial to determine that the result is too large to fit into a short when you typecast back, but to determine that the compiler would be required to perform arithmetic at compile time, then perform a typecast validation check on the result. With very rare exceptions (all called out explicitly in the spec, mostly involving zero-valued constants) the compiler does not check the *results* of operations, only the *types* of operations, and the types of your operations are all correct.

Also, your list of cases where the compiler allows casting is woefully inadequate. The compiler allows typecasts to occur in a pretty wide variety of situations, many of them being completely invisible to the CLR. For example, there are implicit and explicit type conversions built in to the language for every almost every numeric type to every other numeric type. Good places to find additional information on the typecast rules:

- [Explicit Numeric Conversions @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288039%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Implicit Numeric Conversions @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Eric Lippert's posts on the cast operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/cast+operator/)

Comment: Curious that `long` is implicitly convertible to `float`, but `double` isn't, notwithstanding the fact that for every possible `double` value, there is exactly one "best" `float` value, and a `long` can lose a lot of precision in the conversion.  Actually, I'd posit that conversions from `float` to `double` are more apt to be buggy than `double` to `float`.  For example, `float f = (float)(1.0 / 10.0);` is correct within half a least-significant bit, while `double d = 1.0f / 10.0f;` is off by millions.

Answer (score 1):

In general that cast says "I am doing this deliberately, do not complain", so for the compiler to complain would be the surprising behaviour.

There is in fact no overflow because of implicit promotion of the arguments.  The cast however truncates the 32 bit result so that the result is not arithmetically equal to `s + 1`; but because you explicitly requested the cast, the compiler will not complain - it is doing exactly as you have asked.

Moreover there are many cases when "wrap-around" overflow (or modulo-2<sup>n</sup> arithmetic) is deliberate and required. The compiler will reasonably assume that it is required if you explicitly cast to a smaller type.

It is down to the programmer to choose an appropriate type for the operation, and if overflow is undesirable a `float`, `double` or `decimal` may be more appropriate arithmetic types than system-limited integer types.

Comment: without the cast the code won't compile, but it has nothing to do with the ranges, and everything to do with type mismatching.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the clarification (C++ programmer, infrequent C# user!). I meant "explicitly requested the cast" as opposed to "changing the variable type", and was not suggesting that the cast alone be omitted.  The point being if the compiler tells you there is a type mismatch and you "solve" it by casting to an inappropriate type, rather than changing the type of the assigned variable, that is not "detectable" by the compiler because it may be a semantic error, or it may be an application requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to all for your explanations.

Let me also add a citation from Jeffry Richter's book which explains why compiler does not fail when you try to cast Int16 to Int32 while they are not derived from each other:

**From page 116:**

*" (...) the C# compiler
has intimate knowledge of primitive types and applies its own special rules when compiling
the code. In other words, the compiler recognizes common programming patterns and
produces the necessary IL to make the written code work as expected."*

Comment: No offense to Jeffry Richter, but that's a rather lame explanation.  You've received some much better answers already.